# Writing plugin : IDA Pro crashes when I launch a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, ida

IDA pro craches when I try to start thread into the run method, any idea ??

Is there some restriction for running thread in ida ? because I found nothing in documentation, [writing plugin ida](http://www.openrce.org/reference_library/files/ida/idapw.pdf).

```
import idaapi
from threading import Thread
import time

class Listener(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(3)

class myplugin_t(idaapi.plugin_t):
    flags = idaapi.PLUGIN_UNL

    def init(self):
        return idaapi.PLUGIN_OK

    def run(self, arg):
        t1 = Listener();
        t1.start();
        t1.join();

    def term(self):
        pass

def PLUGIN_ENTRY():
    return myplugin_t()
```

PS: The same problem is found when I write the plugin in c++

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can use

```
thread.start_new_thread(functionname, ()) # the second arguments is for args
```

which works in ida pro.

For c++, Any ida ?